# Programatically created files become NULL in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, file, overwrite

I've a shell script which create files programmatically by writing the contents of a variable to a file in the memory location.

```
file=/downloads/fileName.crt
variable="These contents are to be
          written to the file"
echo "$variable" > "$file"
```

This works fine. I'm able to see that the file is written to and not NULL. But sometimes after running this script and after a reboot, the file contents become NULL. Why is this happening?

Link to full code:

[Newly created file becomes NULL on reboot in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612471/newly-created-file-becomes-null-on-reboot-in-linux)

This code is running on an industrial mobile Linux computer with very basic configuration.

Comment: show your actual shell script

Comment: What do you mean by NULL? How do you read the file? Where do you see NULL?

Comment: Hi @AhmedMasud I posted this in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612471/newly-created-file-becomes-null-on-reboot-in-linux

Comment: Hi @vojislavdjukic . After running the script, I navigate to /downloads and am able to see that the files are not NULL using the ls or cat <filename>. But after reboot, if I navigate to the same location, I see that the files exist in the location but are 0 bytes.

Comment: Whatever's causing the file to be emptied out, it's not the couple lines of script you posted. We can't possibly debug this from across the Internet. You'll need to dig into it and find the culprit yourself. There are a million possibilities.

Comment: IMHO, a startup script (this one or another one) clears the files. Could you control if the mod time of the file has changed and is the shutdown or startup time (switch the machine off, wait some minutes and start it up again)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks. I've posted the whole set of files here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612471/newly-created-file-becomes-null-on-reboot-in-linux but I understand what you are saying. I'm trying to debug this but can't get any leads on why this is happening.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks. I had this doubt. I'll try again with a fresh OS installation.

Comment: Don't repost the same question multiple times. This question should be closed as a duplicate of the last one. Your previous question probably got no answers because there's WAY too much information in it. You really need to debug the problem yourself and narrow it down to something manageable. When you have 10 scripts and no idea where to start you're not ready for SO.

Comment: Also, avoid saying "NULL". Pointers can be NULL, not files. If you mean the files are missing, say that. If you mean they're empty (0 bytes), say that.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : After posting that long question, I tried only using the two files: certificateGenerator.sh and applicationAuthenticator.sh. Still having the same problems. I'm not able to arrive at a conclusion, as this problem only happens sporadically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to

```
sync
```

at the end of the script.

Comment: There's no need to arbitrarily call `sync`. It's poor engineering to randomly try things and hope to band-aid over a problem you don't understand.